# AlwaysEncrypted Column error when trying to insert into table

Tags: stored-procedures, encryption, sql-server-2017, always-encrypted, parameterization

lets start with the error first:

*Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables . The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'PLAINTEXT') and the expression near line '3' expects it to be (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_P_H', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'Payments_Hub') (or weaker)*

I'm trying to insert into a column with AlwaysEncrypt encryption on using a stored procedure:

The column 'PARAMETER_VALUE' is the encrypted column

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_UI_Parameter    
(
@ID int OUTPUT,
@OPERATION_ID int,
@PARAMETER_NAME varchar(100),
@PARAMETER_METRIC varchar(100),
@PARAMETER_VALUE varchar(100) 
)
AS
BEGIN

IF @ID IS NULL
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TOKEN_PARAMETER] (OPERATION_ID,
PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_METRIC, PARAMETER_VALUE)

SELECT @OPERATION_ID, @PARAMETER_NAME, @PARAMETER_NAME, @PARAMETER_VALUE

SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
ELSE
BEGIN

UPDATE [dbo].[TOKEN_PARAMETER] SET
OPERATION_ID = @OPERATION_ID,
PARAMETER_NAME = @PARAMETER_NAME,
PARAMETER_METRIC = @PARAMETER_METRIC,
PARAMETER_VALUE = @PARAMETER_VALUE

END

END
GO
```

Why am I getting the error for the query ?

Is there something I must include within the STORED PROCEDURE ?

1. I have included "Column Encryption Setting=Enabled " in my connection settings
2. I have also enabled Parameteterization for AlwaysEncrypted
3. The key is stored on the local machine
4. I have created DETERMINISTIC encryption
5. SQL Server 2016 database Engine using SSMS 17 - can this be an issue ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This code works properly. I'm able to call the SP from SSMS and save data in the encrypted column without errors. Show us how you call it. And probably, you would want to add a where condition to your update statement.

Comment: Hi, please see below link, I have updated my question there.
 https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228640/alwaysencrypted-error-when-inserting-via-stored-proc?noredirect=1#comment450908_228640

Comment: Yes, Parameterization for AlwaysEncrypted maps Transact-SQL variables to query parameters. So you definitely must declare a variable in your query and not pass a literal in the SP call in-place.